# Is there such thing as flushing coolant to often?

Tags: maintenance, coolant, cooling-system, cooling

If I were to go with a coolant flush every 15 to 20 thousand miles is this considered a little too excessive? It’s a ford fiesta mk 6 the service interval by the manufacturer is recommended at 100 thousand miles but I prefer to change it more often as my old Hyundai service interval was only 24 thousand miles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're asking if this will hurt the car, the answer is absolutely not. Well, I guess there is a risk of wearing out the petcock sooner, but other than that, no. You will not void your warranty if you might be wondering if that was a concern.

The only real issue is your pocket book. If you are using the specified coolant from the manufacturer, there's no risk to your vehicle changing the coolant out at the given interval. In this case, by changing it sooner you are only wasting good coolant.

Comment: I drained it out this afternoon, but when i went to refill i noticed cracks in the expansion bottle so guess i will be doing it again once i get a new one of those :( could there be something wrong with the cooling system as my last expansion bottle had really bad cracks. this is a new expansion bottle that is only two years old and it already has small cracks developed i know the cooling system is pressured but surly they should last more than two years without getting cracks

Comment: @ceefax12 - what vehicle are we talking about here? And are the cracks developing leaks? Maybe this should be a separate question for you to ask.